# Coset representatives of $\mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q}$ and cusp forms

Tags: automorphic-forms

I'm reading Deitmar's "Automorphic form" and it said that a function $\varphi\in L^{2}(\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Q})\backslash \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{A})^{1})$ is a *cusp form* if
$$
\int_{N(\mathbb{Q})\backslash N(\mathbb{A})}\varphi(ng)dn = \int_{\mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q}} \varphi\left(\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\&1\end{pmatrix}g\right)dx=0
$$
for almost all $g\in \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{A})^{1}$, where $\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{A})^{1}=\{g\in \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{A})\,:\, |\det(g)|=1\}$.

I think this definition should be compatible with the classical definition of holomorphic cusp forms, so the following formula will holds for $\varphi=\phi_{f}$ where $f\in S_{k}(\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}))$ is a cusp form of weight $k$ and
$$
\phi_{f}(g) = f(g_{\infty}i)j(g_{\infty}, i)^{-k}
$$
where $g_{\infty}$ is a $\infty$-part of $g$ and $j(g_{\infty}, z) = c_{\infty}z+d_{\infty}$. I tried to show this, but I don't know how to integrate over $\mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q}$. So my question can be summarized as follows:

> 1. What is a set of coset representatives of $\mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q}$ and how to integrate over it?
> 2. Why we need a condition that the integral vanishes for **almost all** $g$, not all $g$?

---

Thank you for your answers, and I just found that we have
$$
\mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q}\simeq \prod_{p<\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{p}\times [0,1)
$$
The proof may be found at [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/676Page/handouts/adelelattice.pdf). (I think I saw this few years ago but I completely forgot about this..)

Comment: If [think](http://math.bu.edu/people/jsweinst/Teaching/MA843/AutomorphicReps.pdf)

$\int_{\mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q}}\varphi\left(\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\&1\end{pmatrix}g\right)dx= \int_0^1 f(x+g_\infty i)dx$
 where $f(a+ib) = \varphi(\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix})$ for every $a,b$. If $f$ is holomorphic then $f(z) = \sum_{n=-M}^\infty a_n e^{2i \pi n z}$, if $f$ is  $L^2$ on the fundamental domain then $M \ge 0$ and $f$ is a modular form. If $ \int_0^1 f(x+z)dx = a_0=0$ then $f$ vanishes at the $\infty$ cusp.

Comment: How to verify the first equality?

Comment: I think it would help to define elements of $\mathbb{A}$ as $a= \{a_v \in \mathbb{Q}_v, v \le \infty\}$ and $F(x) = \varphi\left(\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\&1\end{pmatrix}g\right)$ is $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Q}_\infty$ and $ \mathbb{Z}_p$ invariant for each $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 1. It is easy to see (by definition of restricted direct product) that
     $$ \mathbb A = \mathbb Q(\hat {\mathbb Z} \times \mathbb R). $$
     Since the intersection of $\mathbb Q$ (diagonally embedded) and $(\hat {\mathbb Z} \times \mathbb R)$ are the rational numbers which are $p$-adic integers everywhere, this intersection is $\mathbb Z$.  So we get
     $$ \mathbb A/ \mathbb Q = (\hat {\mathbb Z} \times \mathbb R) / \mathbb Z \simeq \hat {\mathbb Z} \times (\mathbb R / \mathbb Z).$$
- 2. The "almost all" condition is because a "for all" condition doesn't make sense for $L^2$-functions.

Also, you seem to be missing a determinant factor in your definition of $j(g,z)$.

The passage from classical modular forms to adelic automorphic forms is explained many places, e.g., Bump's book, Gelbart's book, Cogdell's Fields Institute notes, Kudla's notes in "Introduction to the Langlands Program."

Comment: So are we really looking at $\int_{C/D} \varphi(\gamma g) d\gamma$ 
where $d\gamma$ is the Haar measure on $C/D$ and $C = \{ {\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\&1\end{pmatrix}}, x \in \mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q}\}$ and $D =\{ {\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\&1\end{pmatrix}}, x \in\hat{\mathbb{Z}}\}$, which is in some sense "natural" for functions on $GL_2(\mathbb{A})$ left and right-invariant and $L^2$ under [...]

Comment: @reuns Well the integrand you wrote isn't necessarily invariant under replacing $\gamma$ with $\gamma u$ for some $u \in D$ (it is for some $g$).  But you can first integrate over the compact group $D$ and then over $C/D$ if you like.